# Get data from list using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-lists

I have the webpage- https://dmesupplyusa.com/mobility/bariatric-rollator-with-8-wheels.html
Here there is a list of specifications under details that i want to extract as a table, i.e. the specification category as the header, and the specification value as the next row. How can i do this in python using beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = requests.get("https://dmesupplyusa.com/mobility/bariatric-rollator-with-8-wheels.html").content #Read Page source

page = bs(page) # Create Beautifulsoup object
data = page.find_all('strong', string="Product Specifications")[0].find_next('ul').text.strip().split('\n') # Extract requireed information
data = dict([zip(i.split(":")) for i in data])
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.